# MYSQL IN or multiple conditionals

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, where-clause

I have a simple query which is returning records based on the field `status` not having certain values.
Lets say for arguments sake that the field can have values 1,2,3...10 and I want to return all records that don't have values 3, 7 and 9. Which of the following would be best to use?

Option 1.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tbl` WHERE (`status` != '3' AND `status` != '7' AND `_status` != '9')
```

Option 2.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tbl` WHERE `status` NOT IN ('3','7','9');
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the optimiser would reduce both queries to the same thing, and if that is true I prefer the second option, as it's shorter and thus easier to parse.

You should try running `EXPLAIN` on each query with real data to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to optimize your Query using EXPLAIN Command 
for Example

EXPLAIN SELECT `id` FROM `tbl` WHERE `status` NOT IN ('3','7','9');
and see the execution time